# Sort list based on name of object in list?

Tags: c#

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, which I think it may be although I cannot find the answer I am looking for.

In my list, I need to sort by the names of the objects in the list. As an example, if in a list of `cars` I have the objects `Volvo`, `Ford`, `BMW`, `Audi`, `Ferrari` and `Lamborghini` in *that* order, then I would need it to order the objects `Audi` then `BMW` etc.

I have tried doing `.OrderBy(x => nameof(x))` but this didn't work. Does anyone have any solutions

Edit: I need to order by the following (other elements hidden because of sensitive data):

[image: screenshot of code]

So on `Data` there is an object called "Aaa" for example which needs to be the first element in this list.

Comment: nameof(x) returns "x" if I am not mistaken

Comment: `"x" == nameof(x)`

Comment: What do you mean by "names of the objects"? Does your `Car` type (or whatever) have a `Name` property? It's very hard to help without a [mcve]...

Comment: You should not rely on the names of the variables as they don´t have any meaning for the assembly. However you may consider to add a `Name`-property to the instances in your list. So you can easily use `myList.OrderBy(x => x.Name)`.

Comment: The names of the variables are not maintained when the code is compiled, so the names you give your variables are meaningless when it comes to your program's logic. `nameof` merely cheats a bit to make this less impossible by converting the name into a string literal just before compilation, but it was not intended for this kind of use.

Comment: Your images doesn´t make your question any clearer. I can´t see any car at all, so what are the names you refer to?

Comment: Per edit: The object is *called* "Aah", or the object *contains* "Aah"? You are not making your problem any clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the variables names within a collection you should use a `Name`-property for every instances within that list:

```
class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Now within your consuming code you can easily use this property:

```
var myList = new List<Car> { 
    new Car { Name = "BMW" },
    new Car { Name = "Audi" }
}:
var result = myList.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

As Abion47 and me already mentioned the names of variables have no meaning to the assembly, just within your sour-code. When you de-compile your assembly you see that the names are replaced by a random dummy-name. So relying on those names is hardly a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the way using IComparer interface.

//Implementing IComparer

```
    public  class Cars
    {
       string Name { get; set; }   
    }

    public class SortByName : IComparer<Cars>
    {    
      public int Compare(Cars first, Cars next)
         {
           return first.Name.CompareTo(next.Name);
         }
     }
```

//Main Method

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cars one = new Cars { Name = "Ford" };
            Cars two = new Cars { Name = "Audi" };
            Cars three = new Cars { Name = "Lamborghini" };
            Cars four = new Cars { Name = "Ferrari" };

            List<Cars> _lstCars = new List<Cars>();
            _lstCars.Add(one);
            _lstCars.Add(two);
            _lstCars.Add(three);
            _lstCars.Add(four);
            SortByName sortbyname = new SortByName();
            _lstCars.Sort(sortbyname);
            Console.WriteLine("Result After sorting by name");
            foreach (var item in _lstCars)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
```